# Ionic-Application login solution with 'remember me' function

Tags: angularjs, authentication, ionic-framework, remember-me

I am coding an ionic-framework application with login and 'remember me' function.

I just need to now if it is safe to store the username and the password on the phone with:

```
window.localStorage.setItem('loginMail', $scope.loginData.mail);
window.localStorage.setItem('loginPassword', $scope.loginData.password);
```

In my `$resource-service` I use an interceptor, wich automatically reconnects, when the backend sends a status 401.

Is there a better solution to store mail and password, if `windows.localStorage` is not safe on the phone?

Or how would you suggest to implement such a functionality?

Comment: A more conventional method is to use a session cookie for 'remember me'. Then the password is not saved in plaintext anywhere.

Comment: @HåkenLid: Not a session cookie, but a cookie with a long expiry. Otherwise the "remember me" function, will not remember much when the browser is closed. ;)

Comment: I will ask me college if it is possible to change the REST-Server to handle normal and long-term sessions, I also think it would be the best solution. But as questioned above, is it safe to store some variables in `windows.localStorage`or can they be read by anyone else than the ionic-application?

Comment: @rholtermann: I don't know for sure if this is a security issue or not. When it comes to storing passwords, I will always use an existing system made by people who know a lot more about security than I do. Long time login sessions are implemented by generating a unique token on the server after the user has logged in with password and username. The token is stored in a cookie on the client and in a database (or redis) on the server. The server backend can give each token an expiration time, or invalidate them for any other reason. That just means that the user has to use password next login.

Comment: @SilverlightFox: Thanks. That was what I meant. It's not a session cookie, but a persistent cookie which contains a session token.